# starting another android application to open a photo?

Tags: java, android

I had an interview today for a junior android dev position and one of the questions I was asked was something like this:

You have an application that opens an email. The email has a photo attached to it. How could you give the user the choice of which application to open this photo with? I.e. give them a list of photo opening apps to choose from and then open that application with the photo. You don't know ahead of time what apps are available other than android's default photo viewer.

How the heck do you solve this?

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent intent = new Intent();  
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);  
File file = new File("/sdcard/foo.jpg");  
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "image/*");  
startActivity(intent);
```

In a nutshell, you are telling Android, in an abstract way that you'd like to view a photo. Apps that are able to view photos register their ability to do so in their manifest (they respond to `ACTION_VIEW`, for the given content type `image/*`).

If you wanted to view an HTML file,

```
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("http://www.google.com", "text/html");
```

`ACTION_VIEW` is just one example. There's also an `ACTION_EDIT`, and others.